# Selecting element parent with a specific class and removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an anchor element nested within multiple divs. When I click on it the specific tweet gets deleted from the database using AJAX and I want to visually remove it using jquery but I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="tweet-wrapper w-clearfix"  >
    <div class="tweet-left-side-wrapper"><a href="{{route('show.profile',$tweet->user->profile->url_handle)}}"><img class="tweet-avatar" height="48" src="/images/profiles/{{$tweet->user->profile->image->file}}" width="48"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tweet-right-side-wrapper w-clearfix">
        <a class="tweet-username" href="{{route('show.profile',$user->profile->url_handle)}}">{{$tweet->user->profile->display_name}}</a>
        <a class="tweet-handle" href="{{route('show.profile',$user->profile->url_handle)}}">{{$tweet->user->profile->handle}}</a><span> · </span>
        <a class="tweet-date" href="#">{{$tweet->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</a>

        @if($tweet->user->profile->url_handle == $user->profile->url_handle)

            <div class="tweet-dropdown w-dropdown" data-delay="0">
                <div class="tweet-dropdown-toggle w-dropdown-toggle">
                    <div class="w-icon-dropdown-toggle"></div>
                </div>
                <nav class="tweet-dropdown-list w-dropdown-list">
                    <div class="nav-dropdown-link-group">
                        <a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Share via Direct Message</a>
                        <a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Copy link to Tweet</a>
                        <a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Embed Tweet</a>
                        <a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Pin to your profile page</a>
                        <a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link profile-tweet-delete-button" data-tweet-id="{{$tweet->id}}" href="#">Delete tweet</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-dropdown-link-group"><a class="nav-dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Add to new Moment</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

AJAX:

```
$('.profile-tweet-delete-button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){



        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'{{URL::route('delete-tweet')}}',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data:{
                tweetID : $(this).data('tweet-id')
            }
            ,
            success:function(){
                successAlert("Tweet deleted!");
                $(this).parents('div[class^="tweet-wrapper"]').remove();


            },
            error: function(){
                errorAlert("Failed to delete tweet!");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: First thing I see is that it should be `.parent()` not `parents()`

Comment: `$(this).parent('.tweet-wrapper').remove();`

Comment: `this` inside of the ajax success, I don't think it's the clicked element

Comment: Also closest(".tweet-wrapper").remove()

Comment: Neither closest or parent work. Already tried them. Could it be that the $(this) inside of AJAX success doesn't work?

Comment: @kalvin the `this` inside of the succes does not refer to the clicked element, you need to cache it before the call and use it in the ajax section

Comment: Figured it out. $(this) inside success doesn't work. Question got closed tho :(. Thank you all.

Comment: Goes at top of handler func -> `var theTweetDiv = $(this).closest('tweet-wrapper);`  Then do `theTweetDiv.remove();` inside the success callback.

Comment: `$('.profile-tweet-delete-button').on('click',function(){var linkobj = $(this); $.ajax({type:'post',url:'{{URL::route('delete-tweet')}}',headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},data:{tweetID : $(this).data('tweet-id')},success:function(){successAlert("Tweet deleted!");linkobj.parent('.tweet-wrapper').remove();},error: function(){errorAlert("Failed to delete tweet!");}});});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store `this` outside the `success` callback like so..

```
$('.profile-tweet-delete-button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        var thisRef = this;             // store a ref here
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'{{URL::route('delete-tweet')}}',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data:{
                tweetID : $(this).data('tweet-id')
            }
            ,
            success:function(){
                successAlert("Tweet deleted!");
                $(thisRef).parents('div[class^="tweet-wrapper"]').remove();
            },
            error: function(){
                errorAlert("Failed to delete tweet!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i think each is not required because he will click on links individually at a time